# Combine two rows of one matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix:

```
d = matrix(c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "a"  "a"  "b" 
#[2,] "b"  "c"  "c"
```

And I want to get combination of the two rows:

```
d_res = paste(c("a_b", "a_c", "b_c"), collapse = ",")
# [1] "a_b,a_c,b_c"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=2` and `paste` the elements togther to create a `vector` and then `paste` it again to get a single string.

```
paste(apply(d, 2, FUN= paste, collapse="_"), collapse=',')
#[1] "a_b,a_c,b_c"
```

---

Or we could take the transpose and use only a single `paste` to collapse the columns

```
 d1 <- t(d)
 paste(d1[,1], d1[,2], sep="_", collapse=",")
 #[1] "a_b,a_c,b_c"
```